# Container is not showing up if borderRadius exist

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a custom sliding bottom container with rounded corner using animatedPosition widget, but each time I add borderRadius in the container, the container didn't show up

This is the code that I've been working on

```dart
class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {
  bool show = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            setState(() {
              show = !show;
            });
            print(show);
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new _ProductPageBody(),
                !show
                    ? Positioned.fill(
                        child: Container(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ))
                    : Container(),
                AnimatedPositioned(
                    bottom: show ? -500 : 0,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    curve: Curves.easeIn,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 500,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to implement a BottomSheet?

Comment: yes but with state, the original bottomsheet from flutter is stateles

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the inner Container with ClipRRect

```
   AnimatedPositioned(
                    bottom: show ? -500 : 0,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    curve: Curves.easeIn,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(10),
child: AnyWidget
    ),
                    )),
```